# Body not dropping below Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having CSS/HTML issues with Bootstrap. For some reason it seems the navigation is not pushing down the aspects of the HTML that follows. See https://jsfiddle.net/xaazf6u2/

```
 <div id="topNavigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BCF</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">History <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/history.php?site=FGT">FGT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/history.php?site=BB">BB</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="login" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="pageContent" class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Use the form below to upload an order feed. Once uploaded, FedEx shipping will be purchased, labels and packing slip generated for us. Use the navigation above to access previously generated files.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the examples you can see that the `jumbotron` should have some space below the navigation http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you used the fixed navbar Bootstrap recommends you add padding to your body to prevent this problem.  So in your CSS you need to add

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Answer (score 1):

The navbar is `position:fixed` so that it stays on the screen as you scroll. Elements with fixed position don't affect layout of other elements, so you'll need to manually set margin or padding on them.

See the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#body-padding-required) for notes on this.

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the bottom of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>   Copy
>
> `body { padding-bottom: 70px; }`
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: This is correct but shouldn't it be `padding-top` rather than `padding-bottom`?

Comment: Yes--this quote is copied from the 'fixed to bottom' part of the bs documentation

Answer (score 0):

The class "navbar-fixed-top" means that the content is scrollable and goes under the navbar.

Add a margin-top to the content if you want to keep this feature or remove the "navbar-fixed-top" class if you don't.

Comment: According to bootstrap, you need to change the class from `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-static-top` OR you add `padding-top` to the body instead of a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bar is fixed to the top by default you can change that by removing the class 'navbar-fixed-top'.